# SUMIF formula from dropdowns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a budget spreadsheet to track my personal, non-bill spending. I try to keep certain categories within certain dollar amounts. I have created a column to categorize my transactions that has drop downs.

For example, I allot $50/month for Lunch. I would like to create a second part of my spreadsheet where starting with $50, if column C has Lunch, deduct amount from Column F from starting value. Then it pull every time a row has "Lunch" in the drop down.

I have tried using this thread: [subtract from number IF statment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72623568/subtract-from-number-if-statment)

But I don't think my situation exactly applies.

Comment: It looks like you're working on a budget spreadsheet and trying to deduct amounts based on certain categories. To provide more accurate help, could you please share a sample sheet or a simplified version of your spreadsheet? This would help us better understand your current setup and create a solution that fits your specific needs.

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 I made a copy and here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JIKeQT6312ohRZfRKDph023am8fLjj6_g-wWo_y3ipk/edit?usp=sharing

Over to the right, you can see the amounts for each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this formula in cell B3 based on the following example:

`=sumif(B8:B,"=Lunch",F8:F)`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]